# VPN sever not reachable through local gateway after connecting to PIA VPN service

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, docker, gateway

I have the following situation:

UDM pro
192.168.20.1 default LAN gateway port 6000 forwarded to the server running Docker OpenVPN server.
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
192.168.20.2 Server running Docker VPN server and OpenVPN client to act as internet gateway for local LAN.

As long as I don't connect to PIA on the server everything is fine. When I connect to PIA all traffic to the VPN server drops. I suspect the answer to my VPN clients now gets routed via the default route of the PIA server.

My configs:

```
Iptables:

# Flush
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Block All
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# allow Localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Make sure you can communicate with any DHCP server
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT

# Make sure that you can communicate within your own network
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT

# Allow established sessions to receive traffic:
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow TUN
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun+ -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT

# allow VPN connection
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p udp --destination-port 1197 -m comment --comment "Allow VPN connection" -j ACCEPT

# Block All
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP

# Log all dropped packages, debug only.

iptables -N logging
iptables -A INPUT -j logging
iptables -A OUTPUT -j logging
iptables -A logging -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables general: " --log-level 7
iptables -A logging -j DROP

echo "saving"
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
echo "done"
```

```
route:
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         x.x.x.x         128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun06
default         192.168.20.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s25
10.37.110.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun06
128.0.0.0       x.x.x.x.x       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun06
unn-138-199-18- 192.168.20.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp0s25
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     203    0        0 docker0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     307    0        0 veth4c4488b
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.10.0    192.168.20.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 enp0s25
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 enp0s25
192.168.30.0    192.168.20.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 enp0s25
192.168.40.0    192.168.20.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 enp0s25
192.168.50.0    192.168.20.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 enp0s25
```

I tried everything I could find on the internet including:

policy based routing
2nd NIC and routing through that
changing the default routing via 20.1

Added routes:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.20.2 table 128
ip route add table 128 to 192.168.20.0/24 dev enp0s25
ip route add table 128 default via 192.168.20.1
```

This last one worked a long time ago but for some reason doesn't anymore.
I have disabled the firewall at this stage, because I have a good one on my router and I want to get this working first.

edit:
fixed, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

while looking for something else i found the answer:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Adding default route to $route_vpn_gateway with /0 mask..."
ip route add default via $route_vpn_gateway

echo "Removing /1 routes..."
ip route del 0.0.0.0/1 via $route_vpn_gateway
ip route del 128.0.0.0/1 via $route_vpn_gateway
```

run this after making a vpn connection and it works

source:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692255/how-make-openvpn-work-with-docker